# datagridview dynamic columns and adding issues

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid and a database bind together, I'm using **vb.net** and **vs2012**. My problem is not all columns in database will be displayed in datagrid, it depends on the user what column he wants to display(there is a check list box in form for option what column to display) and also there is one column in database must be separated (I use split here).

**here is my sample db :**

```
  Name  |   col1    |   col2    |   col3    |
---------------------------------------------
aa,bb,cc|   111     |   111     |   111     |
dd,ee,ff|   222     |   222     |   222     |
gg,hh,ii|   333     |   333     |   333     |
---------------------------------------------
```

in that sample db **NAME COLUMN** must be separated every `,` (I already solved that)

**this is my sample code for adding column in data-grid and split-ted :**

```
Dim cl1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Dim cl2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Dim cl3 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

With cl1
    .HeaderText = "SplitName1"
    .Name = "sn1"
    .Width = 120
    .ReadOnly = True
End With

With cl2
    .HeaderText = "SplitName2"
    .Name = "sn2"
    .Width = 120
    .ReadOnly = True
End With

With cl3
    .HeaderText = "SplitName3"
    .Name = "sn3"
    .Width = 120
    .ReadOnly = True
End With

dg.Columns.Insert(0, cl1)
dg.Columns.Insert(1, cl2)
dg.Columns.Insert(2, cl3)

'dynamic column

Dim n As Integer = 3

   'here it count datatable columns if how many columns to make in datagrid 
   'I start in 1 because column 0 is NAME COLUMN

For colcnt As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1 'dt is datable
    Dim dgvtxt As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    With dgvtxt
         .HeaderText = "Column" & colcnt.ToString
         .Name = "col" & colcnt.ToString
         .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader
         .ReadOnly = True
    End With

    dg.Columns.Insert(n, dgvtxt)
    n += 1
Next

'this will be the variables to store the split names
Dim _SName1 As String = Nothing
Dim _SName2 As String = Nothing
Dim _SName3 As String = Nothing

'for splitting column name

Dim charSeparatorsC() As Char = {","c}
Dim sampDataArray() As String

dg.Rows.Clear()

 'loop through records to get values

For counter As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

'splitting procedure

sDataArray = dt2.Rows(counter)(0).ToString.Split(charSeparatorsC, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

'Load data on the sampDataArray to the Sample Name column variable
'If the array is not existing set an empty string

  Try
      _SName1 = sDataArray(0).ToString
  Catch ex As Exception
      _SName1 = ""
  End Try

  Try
      _SName2 = sDataArray(1).ToString
  Catch ex As Exception
      _SName2 = ""
  End Try

  Try
      _SName3 = sDataArray(2).ToString
  Catch ex As Exception
      _SName3 = ""
  End Try

     'Now this is my problem, how to add the dynamic selected columns 
     'from datable since the code below is specified column of a datagrid which is the cl1,cl2, and cl3.
     'My question is how to get the columns from datatable and add to datagrid(sample output below).
  dgRT.Rows.Add(_SName1, _SName2, _SName3)


Next
```

**Expected output :**

If the user selected two columns to display

```
|SplitName1|SplitName2|SplitName3|col1|col2|
|------------------------------------------|
|  aa      |   bb     |   cc     |111 |111 |
|  dd      |   ee     |   ff     |222 |222 |
|  gg      |   hh     |   ii     |333 |333 |
|------------------------------------------|
```

**Thank you in advance! I need a helping idea for this.**

Answer (score 0):

This the the reason why you should not use non scalar values in a database...
You can use key value pairs if you will not know how many 'columns' you will need.

If you had each value in its own column you can just hide the appropiate columns